# Dynamics AX Color Picker

Tags: colors, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, picker

Trying to add a color picker to a field in Dynamics AX 2009.  Found an article providing some very simple steps for creating the color picker as a lookup, but I can't get it to work.

- When creating the extended data type, the FormHelp lookup doesn't include the function SysChooseColor, but it will accept the value if manually entered.
- After adding a field using my color picker data type, the form renders a string edit to the page with a lookup icon.  However, upon clicking the icon, the lookup window that appears is empty.  Tried with and without a valid color value (#AAAAAA) in the field.

Here's the reference I started with: http://www.axaptapedia.com/Color_picker

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at form JmgParameters?

On tab DisplayOptions you can find example of usage the color lookup form.  See at element.colorLookup() method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  (And for the quick response.)

Comment: in ax2012, which form show this sample? , cannot find in the JmgParameters